# Compute variable expressions in mustache templates: what should we get?

Tags: python, ruby, mustache, specifications

Given these hash and [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) template:

Hash:

```
{
'a': 3
}
```

Template:

```
"This is a+2: {{a+2}}"
```

[Ruby](https://github.com/mustache/mustache) and [Python](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron) give me different outputs:

- In ruby, I get:

  ```
  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/mustache-1.1.1/lib/mustache/parser.rb:286:in `error': Unclosed tag (Mustache::Parser::SyntaxError)
  Line 1
    {{a+2}}
  ```
- In python, just empty string

Who is right? What result should we get in official mustache specification: empty string or error (or something else)? I don't know what the result is other programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are *not wrong* as they adhere to Mustache spec requirements (or lack thereof in this case).

1. Mustache [interpolation spec (v1.2.2)](https://github.com/mustache/spec/blob/v1.2.2/specs/interpolation.yml) only restricts that:

> The tag's content MUST be a non-whitespace character sequence NOT containing
> the current closing delimiter.

2. Mustache spec does not explicitly [Define syntax of tag names (mustache/spec#67)](https://github.com/mustache/spec/issues/67).

The Ruby implementation [mustache/mustache](https://github.com/mustache/mustache) further [constrains the tag name](https://github.com/mustache/mustache/blob/v1.1.1/lib/mustache/parser.rb#L80-L81) to:

```rb
# The content allowed in a tag name.
ALLOWED_CONTENT = /(\w|[?!\/.-])*/
```

The Python implementation [noahmorrison/chevron](https://github.com/noahmorrison/chevron) considers `a+2` as the tag name:

```py
import chevron
chevron.render("This is a+2: {{a+2}}", {'a+2': 3})
# 'This is a+2: 3'
```

Notably, the Python implementation is not defaulting a syntax error to an empty string.

Comment: Can someway to circumvent this limitation? I was thinking in something like this template: `"The four consecutive integers from {{a}} are: {{a+1}}, {{a+2}}, {{a+3}} and {{a+4}}"`. Logic-less is not calculate-less.